# Trying to find a file that doesnt exist Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, swiftmailer

Im trying to create an email function that sends a file attached.

I've created the function and added attach() with the route of file I want to attach as follows:

```
public function newMonthlyBillingRegister(Clinic $clinic, ClinicMonthlyBilling $clinicMonthlyBilling)
{
    $countryAdmins = $clinic->findCountryAdmins($clinic->country->id);
    $adminEmails = [];

    foreach ($countryAdmins as $admin) {
        $adminEmails[$admin->email] = $admin->fullName;
    }

    /** @var BaseMailer $mailer */
    $mailer = Yii::$app->mailer;

    $mailer->htmlLayout = 'layouts/standard_html';
    //$mailer->htmlLayout = 'layouts/invoice_html';
    // $mailer->textLayout = 'layouts/invoice_text';

    try{
        return $mailer
                ->compose(
                    ['html' => 'newMonthlyBillingRegister-html', 'text' => 'newMonthlyBillingRegister-text'],
                    [
                        'clinic'               => $clinic,
                        'clinicMonthlyBilling' => $clinicMonthlyBilling,
                    ]
                )
                ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::t('app', 'support-email-name', ['appName' => Yii::$app->name])])
                ->setTo($adminEmails)
                ->setSubject(Yii::t('app', '[CLINIC][BACKOFFICE] A clinic has upgraded its information in Guarantee Fund Modal.'))
                ->attach('app/media/uploads/clinic/monthly-billing/'.$clinicMonthlyBilling->trimestralBillingFile)
                ->queue() && YII_DEBUG && Yii::$app->mailqueue->process();
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
        LogService::getLogger()->error("Error while sending mail.","EmailService:newMonthlyBillingRegister()",$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

It gave me an error, but the problem comes when I delete attach() from my code, reverting all my changes on this email function, and when I try to send again the email the following message appears:

```
PHP Warning: fopen(app/media/uploads/clinic/monthly-billing/user_1_clinic_1_trimestral_billing_file_2019_05_09_08_22_35): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/ByteStream/FileByteStream.php on line 142
```

The user_1_clinic_1_trimestral_billing_file_2019_05_09_08_22_35 file doesnt exist in app/media/uploads/clinic/monthly-billing/ folder and even in my database

...what's wrong?¿ I know is in my local but I dont know the reason of trying to search a file that doesn't exist and I didn't code anything to search it,

Anyone can help? Im using PHPStorm,

Thanks a lot for your attention!

Comment: May be your queue have pending emails to send with attachment. Try after clearing the queue.

Comment: it was!! Thanks a lot my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to clean my email queue and it worked!! Thanks a lot Insane Skull for your help ;)

Comment: Accept your own answer! :-)